# Laravel framework index.php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a project in laravel5 and I have directed virtual host on /public directory. Where should be my main page index.php now? There is some index.php in public folder already but it contains some content that I dont understand. So where should be my index now? Maybe in views?

Comment: You don't change that public/index.php .. Leave it as it is- that's the right place. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @tanjir  I've read million times that the first, main page, should be always named "index" so thats I'm trying to do :D

Comment: You mentioned "There is some index.php in public folder already"- :D So, it's already there- don't panic! when you try to browse to the location, what do you get?

Comment: Now I see! No, it shouldn't be called "index"- it's index.html typically. If you have php installed, then it's index.php. Depends on how you set it in your web server. You can have default.html- that's how it's set in IIS (windows). As I said, you are fine at this part. are you having an error or something?

Comment: @tanjir  I guess that my question was kinda stupid. So everything means that i dont need index.php page at all in my project? My first page of my website dont have to be called index?

Comment: No, what I said is, you already have index.php- so relax! For naming convention- index.php/index.html is just  default homepage in apache/php. You can have "DirectoryIndex fun.php" in your htaccess file- that will look for fun.php as your default home page :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Laravel 5.1 then your initial page should be this `resources/views/welcome.blade.php`.

You can change it to any name. But also you should change the same in your `Controller`.

**Note :** If you are rendering the view through controller then you should have the file name like this `yourfilename.blade.php`

Your views should always inside `resources/views/*`

Comment: Isn't it a problem for google? I thought they collect keywords etc mostly from index.php while positioning my page.

Comment: No that's not the problem for google until you block them by robots.txt

Comment: +one for you to encourage ur rnd !

Answer (score 1):

The index file stays at the same place, to call a new file that you made, could be with HTML, you can put that file in the view and call it from the controller, hope this is the answer you are looking for.

Comment: Yeah, but shouldn't my main page be called index? For google reasons or anything? i dont know xD

Comment: yea your main page is called index, but you can change it ofcourse, but its easier if you call other view files from the controller which follows the MVC way.

Comment: Of course your main file is `index.php`. Go to the bottom of the index page and read the comments. There are a lot of things you can learn from comments in Laravel. If you are little handy with OOP try to check all of the classes and methods used in `index.php` then you may understand how this framework works and how we see our customize files from view folder.

Answer (score 1):

When a request come to your server, the first file that it is executed is `index.php`. But this is not the file shown. In Laravel you don't have to force any file be named `index.php`. So let's imagine that you are trying set up a new index file. You have to use `routes.php`

**routes.php**

```
Route::get("/" , "HomeController@index");
```

**HomeController.php**

```
function index(){
    return view("home/index");
}
```

**views/home/index.blade.php**

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Index page</p>
</body>
</html>
```

When a `GET` request to `"/"` it's done, the `index` function of the `HomeController` it's executed and the view `index.blade.php`, stored in `views/home` it's shown.

This it's the basic behaviour of Laravel. So you mustn't rename or move the `index.php` file in `public` folder.

Comment: Thanks for another great answer!